# UIView Doesn't allow swipe down to see rest of the screen

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I build a view that has contents which exceed the height of the iphone 6 screen vertically.
To test that out, I've set a specific height for my image (600pts) to guarantee that the whole content wouldn't fit on the screen of an iphone 6 and that you should swipe down to see the rest (the label "BYE").
However, when I run the simulator, I cannot swipe down to see the rest of the screen.

I've used Autolayout constraint and set a margin top/bottom between each components and the superview (I don't have any autolayout constraints issues/warning).

Here's the screenshot of the storyboard of my UIViewController:
[image]

Here's when I run the simulator, I cannot see the Label "BYE"(which is normal) but I cannot swipe down to see it.
[image]

I am using Xcode 6.1 and Swift.
Any suggestion and explanations?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You just need to apply correct `AutoResizing` constraints, or `AutoLayout` constraints if you are using `AutoLayout`.

Comment: Sorry everyone, I forgot to tell that I indeed have used AutoLayout contraint. I've put margin top and bottom between each components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have redone your screen and here are the steps. The reason for your issue is not setting proper constraints in autolayout. First you need to choose `AnyWidth AnyHeight` in Xcode which is in bottom of the storyboard.

Here is the screenshots of View in StoryBoard and its constraints 
 [image]

**Constraints**

[image]

Final Result in Simulator

[image]

Setting the constraint properly will work for you. Let me know if you have any issues in doing so. Sorry for the image i used its low quality one and its just for test.

**EDIT**
In Storyboard if you see the bottom of the screen you will see below image. In center of that image there is `wAnyhAny`.
[image]

Comment: Hi Vino, Thanks a lot for taking the time to answer my question.
I've updated my screenshot (see above) of my constraint. The difference is that I have set a specific height (500pts) for my image which is why everything doesn't fit on the screen and you would require to swipe down to see it.
Can you tell me exactly where to find Anywidth, AnyHeight?

Comment: @fabdarice I have updated the answer for anywidth and anyheight. Why do you need to set a specific height?. If you want to support all screen sizes you need to remove that.

Comment: you're right, I've deleted the specific height for the image. but let's say, I set my UIImage as "Aspect Fill" and the height of the image is 300. Then my "Hello" label is replace by a very long text. then only half of UIImage is displayed on the screen. Why can't I just swipe down to see the rest of my UIImage + the "BYE" label? I don't understand why I just can't, when while I'm using a tableview, I can

Comment: If you want to implement that then you need to consider using `UIScrollView`. It will do what you need. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, It should be related to UIScrollView indeed !

Answer (score 0):

you need add constraint to thoes components! 
Otherwise, some components will be placed out of the screen!

You can learn how to use `Autolayout` from [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1)

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, I've used Autolayout to set up each of my components inside my view. Regardless, it didn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

![enter image description here][1]At right bottom of storyboard in xcode you will see triangel Resolve autolayout isuue select in Reset to suggested constraint.

Comment: sorry, I don't have the triangle as I've used Autolayout constraints properly.

Comment: there are 4 icons align, pin and resolve autolayout issue. in thate reste suggested constraint will solve your issue

Comment: Sorry I know this feature but there's nothing to solve as I don't have any constraints issues. Regardless, I've tried to reset to suggested constraints and it is still the same